# Facebook and "image card space"

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

*Using Facebook SDK for iOS ver 3.1.4*

After submitting an iOS app using the FB SDK's "publish actions", it got rejected as the user message field was pre-filled. So we went and deleted the pre-defined text.

However, we still want to attach an image, and FB told us in the same reply "Please use the image card space" to customize the content for users. As far as I've searched, this "image card space" manual does not seem to exist.

I would like to:

1. Post an image
2. Post a pre-defined text with the accompanied image

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

FYI, this is the help image they gave us on the feedback
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jPRY.png

Comment: Share a link, then you can specify the image as thumbnail for the link, and fill title and description with the values you like. If the user wants to add a message, then it has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user.

Comment: Thanks, I guess ill be doing that!

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled a bit to understand the so called '**image card space**', thinking this was some sort of technical term. As it turns out, facebook wants you to create an image with whatever content you want to post from your side. **Do not** put any custom content into the aptly named 'user message field'.

Additionally, facebook emphasizes on letting the user know what will get posted by the app. So always show a preview of the image you are posting on facebook, before you start posting.